# How to reduce the height of the heatmap itself while increasing the height of the horizontal side bar?

Tags: r, data-visualization, heatmap

In the `heatmap.2` function in the `gplots` package, how can I reduce the height of the rows in the heatmap itself while increasing the height of the horizontal side bar (denoted by `ColSideColors` argument)?

```
library('gplots')
prob_matrix=replicate(100, rnorm(20)) 
ids=paste("patient",c(1:100),sep="_")
type_colors=sample(c("red","blue","cyan","pink","yellow","green"), length(ids), replace = TRUE, prob = NULL)
heatmap.2(prob_matrix, ColSideColors=type_colors,RowV=NULL,trace="none")
```

I would like the horizontal side bar generated by `ColSideColors=subtype_colors` to be increased in height, and the rows of the heatmap reduced in height.

For extension, how can I also edit the width of each column **independent** of the size of the width of the pdf or graphics device to which I output the plot? So, in the above, I would want to make the width of the columns of the `prob_matrix` heatmap greater.

Comment: Great. I made a small edit, now I can cut n paste it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its hard coded into the function. Roundabout line 196 of the `heatmap.2` function there is:

```
if (!missing(ColSideColors)) {
            if (!is.character(ColSideColors) || length(ColSideColors) != 
                nc) 
                stop("'ColSideColors' must be a character vector of length ncol(x)")
            lmat <- rbind(lmat[1, ] + 1, c(NA, 1), lmat[2, ] + 
                1)
            lhei <- c(lhei[1], 0.2, lhei[2])
        }
```

And that 0.2 is the height assigned to the colour bars. If you make a copy of `heatmap.2` and edit it you can set that to something else. Create a new argument, `ColSideHeight` maybe, with default 0.2, and change that 0.2 to `ColSideHeight`.

Comment: Thanks that works. How can I reduce the height of the heatmaps's rows? I've been playing around with the `lmat` and `lhei` arguments but with no success.

Comment: Managed to do it now. Thanks.